# jquery click and calculation on more input

Tags: jquery, click, onchange

I'm a newbie in Jquery:

I've a click function and a change function: it seems that the change function "stop" the job of click function:

```
$(".calc").click(function() {


    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

        $("#p" + i).val(parseFloat((parseFloat($("#amount" + i).val())) / (parseFloat($("#q" + i).val()))).toFixed(5)).change();


    }

});

$('.priceRow').change(function() {

    var q1 = parseFloat($('#q1').val(), 10);
    var qval1 = 0;
    if (q1 > 0) {
        qval1 = q1;
    }

    var q2 = parseFloat($('#q2').val(), 10);
    var qval2 = 0;
    if (q2 > 0) {
        qval2 = q2;
    }

    var p1 = parseFloat($('#p1').val(), 10);
    var puval1;
    if (p1 > 0) {
        puval1 = p1;
    }
    var p2 = parseFloat($('#p2').val(), 10);
    var puval2 = 0;
    if (p2 > 0) {
        puval2 = p2;
    }

    var subtot1;

    subtot1 = parseFloat(qval1 * puval1);

    var subtot2;
    subtot2 = parseFloat(qval2 * puval2);
    var subtot = 0;

    $('#amount1').val(parseFloat(subtot1).toFixed(2)).change();
  //  $('#amount2').val(parseFloat(subtot2).toFixed(2)).change();


});
```

});

html code

```
<div class="priceRow">
q1 : <input id="q1" value="0" class="priceRow"/>
p1 : <input id="p1" value="0" class="priceRow"/>
<a href="#" id="calc2" class="calc">calc</a>
</div>
<div class="priceRow">
 q2 :  <input id="q2" value="0"/>
 p2 :  <input id="p2" value="0" />
<a href="#" id="calc2" class="calc">calc</a> 
</div>
<br>
amount1: <input id="amount1" class="subtot">  </span><br>
amount2: <input id="amount2" class="subtot">  </span><br>
</p>
```

the click function not works on the second row: what's my mistake???

Many Thanks

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/skipperit/mCnqH/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start all over.

ID's can not be duplicated in a page. You should use class instead.

To work only with elements in a `row` you want to traverse to the main parent of the row using `closest()` and use `find()` to only look for elements in that row

Example:

```
$(".calc").click(function(){
   /* "this" is the current element clciked*/

    var $row= $(this).closest( '.priceRow')
     var q1=$row.find('.q1');/* note using class="q1" not ID*/
});
```

`change` event only happens on form inputs, so your `$('.priceRow').change` will never fire

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is to attach the change event handler to the text boxes within price rows. A change event on a div is iffy, at best. Try updating your change event attachment to the following.

```
$('.priceRow input:text').change(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
class="priceRow"
```

to your input fields having id **p2** and **q2** . Currently only **p1** and **q1** have that

http://jsfiddle.net/mCnqH/5/